# Insert file in Wordpress form

Tags: php, wordpress

I have to create a simple form in Wordpress which contains (`name`, `title`)
the form now is insert data correctly using

```
    $wpdb->insert(......)
```

how to add `file` field, the accepted files is (`pdf`, `doc` and `docx`)

how to do this action?